# Android String.format not working as expected

Tags: java, android, string-formatting

## Problem

I expected `"%02f"` to show my int with leading zeroes where applicable.

## Question

How do I format a double of `2.0` into a string of `"02"` with `String.format` ?

## Code

```
 int time = ((Long)task.result).intValue(); // time: 3166

 double days = Math.floor(time / 1440); // days: 2.0
 double hours = Math.floor(time / 60); // hours: 52.0
 double mins = Math.floor(time % 60); // mins: 46.0

 String dayStr = String.format("%02f", days); // dayStr: "2.00000"
 String hourStr = String.format("%02f", hours); // hourStr: "52.00000"
 String minStr = String.format("%02f", mins); // minStr: "46.00000"

 daysTxt.setText(dayStr);
 hoursTxt.setText(hourStr);
 minsTxt.setText(minStr);
```

Comment: Ha, the referred duplicate question is also a duplicate question. Thanks all!

Comment: Also consider [`NumberFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html) and [`setMinimumIntegerDigits`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html#setMinimumIntegerDigits(int))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so using below:

```
String dayStr = String.format("%02.0f", days);
```